# Request URL in Go

Tags: go

I like to ask, if how can i run URL using go. I have ruby code that i like to convert to Go.

```
url4 = "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/xml?api_key=KEY&api_secret=SECRET&from=Aphelion&to=#{params[:user][:mobile_num]}&text=Test SMS"
encoded_url3 = URI.encode(url4)
url5= URI.parse(encoded_url3)
req3 = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url5.to_s)
res = Net::HTTP.start('rest.nexmo.com', 80) {|http|
  http.request(req3)
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I think maybe a better title is "How do I fetch remote content in Go?"  But the extraneous parameters and function calls confuses me enough that I'm not going in for another edit :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard [net/http](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package provides a default http client for performing http requests.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        resp, err := http.Get("https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/xml")
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s", body)
}
```